# Creating a timeline view in swiftui messes up alignment

Tags: swiftui, alignment

I need to create an interactive "timeline" view, that can be panned and zoomed, in SwiftUI (2.0, iOS 14). Think of a media player's progress view, but interactive. The audio needs to be some shape (I just chose RoundedRectangle as example below) and the "current" time needs to be denoted as a vertical (yellow) line in middle of screen.

[image: At zoom level 1]

As I need to be able to both set and get the offset, I am unable to use a horizontal ScrollView. Instead, I just thought of changing the frame size of the shape based on zoom level. The "current" time line is then painted as overlay. At zoom levels up to 0.5, everything works fine.

However, when I zoom in (i.e. make the value of zoomLevel smaller than 0.45), the alignment just goes haywire. I have tried ZStack and a few other combinations without luck. I believe the issue is that the shape size is causing the overlay's location to be miscalculated, but even with ZStack alignment set to [.leading, .center] I am unable to get the yellow line and the shape aligned.

[image: At zoom level 0.3]

Here is the code. What can I do to ensure that as I resize the shape, the overlay yellow line as well as the offset for the shape are calculated correctly so that they remain in center of screen?

```
    let zoomLevel:CGFloat = 1  // This is the value being modified
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .offset(x: getOffset(with: geometry.size.width))
                    .frame(width: getWidth(with: geometry.size.width), height: 150)
                    .overlay(Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 2, height: geometry.size.height/5)
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    )
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
        }
    }
```

and the functions are:

```
    
    private func getOffset(with width: CGFloat)->CGFloat {
        let currentWidth = getWidth(with: width)
        let offset = currentWidth/2 + 0  // 0 would be replaced with pan offset later

        if offset > currentWidth/2 {
            return currentWidth/2
        } else if offset < -currentWidth/2 {
            return -currentWidth/2
        }
        return offset
    }
    
    private func getWidth(with width: CGFloat)->CGFloat {
        return 0.45*width/zoomLevel
    }
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but, from prior experience, I know that GeometryReader aligns content to .topLeading. I suspect you want to align content to .topCenter. The easiest way to do so would be to change .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) to .frame(width: geometry.size.width).

Comment: @Baglan that fixed the issue! Do you want to post your comment as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It's alright, happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Baglan this is resolved - I needed to set `.frame(width: geometry.size.width)` instead of `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)`